# How to create a map key from a variable?

Tags: scala

I would like to create a `Map` from variables, for example:

```
scala> val a = "H"
a: String = H

scala> val b = "C"
b: String = C

scala> Map(a, b)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: (?, ?)
       Map(a, b)
           ^
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: (?, ?)
       Map(a, b)
          ^
```

As you can see, the compiler complains. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using wrong definition of Map. `Map(a -> b)` would work

Comment: Map(a->b) should work

Answer (score 2):

Scala's syntax for instantiating `Map`s looks like this:

```
val myMap: Map[K, V] = Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, ...)
```

where `K` is the type of the keys, and `V` the type of the values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your snippet is that there is not constructor/apply method to build a `Map`  that takes two string arguments.

The right approach/syntax for a Map of String keys and String values would be:

```
val a = "H"
val b = "C"
val testMap: Map[String, String] = Map(a -> b)
```

In general use this syntax:

```
val testMap: Map[K, V] = Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, ...)
```